# How to insert a single row to a Wordpress database table?

Tags: php, database, function, wordpress

Intro:

I have a function that handles a contact form variables in my website.

- user enters name, email and text.
- function.php gets variables using javascript.
- I get more information on the user on the way - like IP, Country, UTM tags if any, ect.

Then I added a code part that saves the variables respectively on a SQL table.

I created the table 'wp_contact_form' using phpMyAdmin.

used this code part in a function:

```
global $wpdb; 

$wpdb->insert( 
    'wp_contact_form', 
    array( 
        'con_ip'          => $_COOKIE['ip'], 
        'con_name'        => $fullname, 
        'con_email'       => $email, 
        'con_text'        => $message, 
        'con_country'     => $_COOKIE['country'], 
        'con_reigon'      => $_COOKIE['region'], 
        'con_city'        => $_COOKIE['city'], 
        'con_utm_source'  => $_COOKIE['utm_source'], 
        'con_utm_medium'  => $_COOKIE['utm_medium'], 
        'con_utm_campain' => $_COOKIE['utm_campaign'], 
        'con_utm_term'    => $_COOKIE['utm_term'], 
        'con_utm_content' => $_COOKIE['utm_content']
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s', 
        '%s', 
        '%s', 
        '%s', 
        '%s', 
        '%s', 
        '%s', 
        '%s', 
        '%s'
    ) 
);
```

And I still get a blank table. 
I tried following this: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows

without any success.

db structure: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ8oZ.png
[image]

Full function code:

```
/**
    Contact form using Ajax 
**/ 

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_contact_form', 'submit_contact_form'); 

// Send information from the contact form 
function submit_contact_form(){

    // Get the UTM variables from the 'get_the_utm_vars()' function
    //$utm = get_the_utm_vars();

    // If there is a $_POST['email']...
    if( isset($_POST['email']) && ($_POST['validation'] == true ) ) {

        // Get parameters
        $email = $_POST['email']; // Gets the email of the user..
        $email_to = "arik@ example.pro";
        $utm_emails = array(
            'tova@ example.pro',
            'yonatan@ example.pro', 
            'arik@ example.pro',
            'gal@ example.pro',  
            'shai@ example.pro',  
            'walid@ example.pro'        
            );
        $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
        $message = $_POST['text']; 
        $email_subject = " example Intro: $email";      
        $headers = array(
                'From: '. $fullname .' <'. $email .'>', 
                'BCC:  yonatan@ example.pro', 
                'BCC:  gal@ example.pro', 
                'BCC:  eran@ example.pro', 
                'BCC:  tova@ example.pro', 
                'BCC:  walid@ example.pro', 
                'Content-type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"; format=flowed \r\n'
            ); 
        $utm_headers = array(
            'From: '. $fullname .' <'. $email .'>'
            );


        // Send email to YH, and if sent - do:
        if ( wp_mail($email_to,$email_subject,$message,$headers) ) {

            // Tells me that the mail has been sent
            echo json_encode( array("result"=>"complete") );

            //Add the UTM variables to the emails text
            $message .= "\r\n \r\n \r\n IP: ". $_COOKIE['ip'] ."\r\n Country: ". $_COOKIE['country'] ."\r\n Region: ". $_COOKIE['region'] ."\r\n City: ". $_COOKIE['city'] ." \r\n UTM Source: ".$_COOKIE['utm_source']." \r\n UTM Medium: ".$_COOKIE['utm_medium']." \r\n UTM Campaign: ".$_COOKIE['utm_campaign']."\r\n UTM Term: ".$_COOKIE['utm_term']." \r\n UTM Content: ".$_COOKIE['utm_content']." ";
            // A mail for tova with the UTM paramseters
            wp_mail($utm_emails,$email_subject,$message,$utm_headers);


        } else {
            echo json_encode(array("result"=>"mail_error"));
            var_dump($GLOBALS['phpmailer']->ErrorInfo);
    }
        wp_die();
    }










    global $wpdb; 

    $wpdb->insert( 
        'wp_contact_form', 
        array( 
            'con_ip'          => $_COOKIE['ip'], 
            'con_name'        => $fullname, 
            'con_email'       => $email, 
            'con_text'        => $message, 
            'con_country'     => $_COOKIE['country'], 
            'con_reigon'      => $_COOKIE['region'], 
            'con_city'        => $_COOKIE['city'], 
            'con_utm_source'  => $_COOKIE['utm_source'], 
            'con_utm_medium'  => $_COOKIE['utm_medium'], 
            'con_utm_campain' => $_COOKIE['utm_campaign'], 
            'con_utm_term'    => $_COOKIE['utm_term'], 
            'con_utm_content' => $_COOKIE['utm_content']
        ), 
        array( 
            '%s', 
            '%s', 
            '%s', 
            '%s', 
            '%s', 
            '%s', 
            '%s', 
            '%s', 
            '%s'
        ) 
    );







}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
     global $wpdb;
            $table = wp_contact_form;
            $data = array(
        'con_ip'          => $_COOKIE['ip'], 
        'con_name'        => $fullname, 
        'con_email'       => $email, 
        'con_text'        => $message, 
        'con_country'     => $_COOKIE['country'], 
        'con_reigon'      => $_COOKIE['region'], 
        'con_city'        => $_COOKIE['city'], 
        'con_utm_source'  => $_COOKIE['utm_source'], 
        'con_utm_medium'  => $_COOKIE['utm_medium'], 
        'con_utm_campain' => $_COOKIE['utm_campaign'], 
        'con_utm_term'    => $_COOKIE['utm_term'], 
        'con_utm_content' => $_COOKIE['utm_content']
            );
            $format = array(
        '%s', 
        '%s', 
        '%s', 
        '%s', 
        '%s', 
        '%s', 
        '%s', 
        '%s', 
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s'
            );
           $success=$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );
            if($success) {
echo 'success';
} else {
echo 'not success';

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$table = wp_contact_form;` be `$table = "wp_contact_form";` ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment as many fields we are inserting we have to use that many %s .

But you are using 9 format %s and there are 12 values you are inserting.